# how to validate CaptchaMVC in Server side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using CaptchaMVC in my Asp.net MVC project. below is my client side code. I am posting this Captcha to an action method. I am stuck how to validate this Captcha in Server side.
my Captcha control in View is below

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Hidden(MvcApplication.MultipleParameterKey, 2)
    @Html.Captcha("Refresh", "", 5, "<span style='color:red'>"+Generals.captchrequired+"</span>", true, new ParameterModel(MvcApplication.MultipleParameterKey, 2))
    <label class="text-danger">@ViewBag.message</label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add only [CaptchaVerify("Captcha is not valid")] filter above on your action method like below

```
 [HttpPost, CaptchaVerify("Captcha is not valid")]
     public  ActionResult Index(YourModelclass obj)
              {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                 return View("Index", obj);
               }
           }
```